# can I tell to useradd to execute a script? Maybe in /etc/default/useradd?

Tags: ssh, sshd, useradd, cluster

There are plenty of people that already answered to the question "how to execute useradd properly in a script?"

My question is: "is it possible to tell to useradd to execute one script when it is called?"

I am writing a script to push identities files (ssh-keys) in an HPC cluster when a user is created, but I think the "cleanest" way would be to write a script that is executed **by** useradd.

The script should do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# sshpush.sh
#
# a script to SSH without passwords around the cluster nodes

mkdir $HOME/.ssh
cd $HOME/.ssh

ssh-keygen -q

cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys

cat > config <<EOF
StrictHostKeyChecking no
FallBackToRsh no
BatchMode yes
ConnectionAttempts 5
UsePrivilegedPort no
Compression no
Cipher blowfish
CheckHostIP no
EOF

cpush /etc/passwd
cpush /etc/shadow
cpush /etc/groups
```

notice that the /home directory is mounted as NFS on all nodes.

Ideally, the script should be executed **at the end** of the user creation  process, after that `$HOME`is created and that the user as a valid group and id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that that isn't an option here (Fedora 19, shadow-utils-4.1.5.1-5.fc19). It sounds like a very useful extension, though. Please report this as a request for enhancements in your distribution's bugtracker (or where that should go).

Comment: mmmh, It seems like it isn't. I have looked in the source code of Useradd and I don't see anything like that. This is sad. Maybe I try to write it once I got a few hours...

Comment: Does the `skel` directory (files to add to a new account) help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if useradd can call another script and execute it with sudo privileges, but you could add a script under /etc/profile.d/ to run only the first time a newly created user logs in. Again, this is a work-around and I am not sure if this script can be run as sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done a lot of testing with your case, but sometimes you can use `alias command=` to change what *command* does. Try it with `ls` first and play around with it to learn how aliasing can work. When you're done, just say `unalias ls` and the shell builtin will resume working.